# Lua spawnpoint random

Tags: lua

my problem is that he uses all 3 spawn points instead of only 1 of the 3 that I put there to choose from

```html
YY_Pos = {}    
YY_Pos[1] = {m=3017299663, x=1700, y=13154, z=2450}
YY_Pos[2] = {m=3017299663, x=1775, y=12413, z=2436}
YY_Pos[3] = {m=3017299663, x=1775, y=12413, z=2500}

function YY_tmhz_1_OnCreatureDisappear(MapID, InstanceID, Creatur ID, x, y, z)
        for i = 1,3 do 
        local Index_pos = math.random(1,3)


        local CreatureID = map.MapCreateCreature(YY_Pos[i].m, InstanceID, 1534207, YY_Pos[i].x, YY_Pos[i].y, YY_Pos[i].z)
        
end
end
```

Comment: Hint: `i` vs. `Index_pos`

Comment: Also, after correct your index indicator maybe you'll need to initialize the `math.randomseed`.

Answer (score 0):

You create a random value `Index_pos` but you never use it.
Instead you use the loop counter variable `i` to index your coordinate table.

Also note that the code as is will not use 1 of three coordinates but 3 random coordinates.
You would have to move the math.random call out of the loop if you want to do something 3 times for the same random index.